# A communication error has been detected PHP DB2 Connection

Tags: php, db2

I have tried to connect to DB2/AS400 remote database with db2cli odbc module and odbc_connect but returns the next error:

> Execution failed: [unixODBC][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N A
>   communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being
>   used: "TCP/IP". Communication API being used: "SOCKETS". Location
>   where the error was detected: "10.10.100.5". Communication function
>   detecting the error: "recv". Protocol specific error code(s): "*",
>   "*", "0". SQLSTATE=08001

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$database = 'xxxx';
$user = 'xxxx';
$password = 'xxxx';
$hostname = '10.10.100.5';
$port = '55000';
$driver = 'DB2';

$conn_string = "DRIVER={$driver};DATABASE=$database;HOSTNAME=$hostname;PORT=$port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=$user;PWD=$password;";

if (!$db = odbc_connect ($conn_string, $user, $password)) {
     print("Execution failed:\n");
}

else echo 'Success!';


odbc_close($db);
```

Help me please!!

Comment: The configuration is not correct. Try to do: telnet 10.10.100.5 55000

Comment: Did you install the [IBM i Access software](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/linux/guide.html) and verify that it works?

Comment: Does the connection fail right away or does it fail later on?

Comment: Here is an article from IBM regarding that error. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21673820

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with AS400, but on Linux/UNIX this error happens when the TCP/IP communication has not been set properly at the server side. There are two things I would check (on a Linux/UNIX server, not sure about the AS400 equivalents):

1. `netstat -na`
2. `db2set DB2COMM=TCPIP`

The first command will return the list of open TCP/IP listeners. Your port 55000 should be on the list. If it is not, it means the server is not open for communication.

The second part enables TCP/IP communication in DB2. Note that there are dependencies on `/etc/services` and the `SVCENAME` DBM CFG parameter. The server must be restart for `DB2COMM` to take effect. When enabled properly, DB2 should start listening at the configured port.

If none of this helps, then it is possible that a firewall is blocking access to the DB2 server.

Again, I apologize if this reply does not apply to AS400.